# bootstrap popover with container set for the "body" does not remove the popover if the target element is removed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/eduardojribeiro/fScua/297/

```
<a class='btn btn-danger button' rel="popover">Click Here</a>

$('body').popover({
    selector: '[rel=popover]',
    trigger: "hover",
    container: "body",
    title: "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    content: "Phasellus lobortis, tortor iaculis viverra bibendum, est nunc lobortis justo"
});

$('.button').click(function(){ $(this).remove() });
```

Comment: Add `$(".popover").hide()` along with `$(this).remove()` [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eduardojribeiro/fScua/297/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `selector` attribute to destroy/hide the popover: http://jsfiddle.net/fScua/363/

```
$('.button').click(function(){ 
    $('[rel=popover]').popover('destroy');
    $(this).remove() ;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `onclick` with your button so on click, it will hide the `popover`. Like:

```
 <a class='btn btn-danger button' rel="popover"
 onclick="$('.popover').hide()">Click Here</a>
```